# Node.js MongoDb with mongoose custom json response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that replays with the data below when i get all documents.
But i would like to add a custom "grouping" to it so it looks like example 2 below.
And i though you could do it by using Population but im not getting it to work..

**Original json**

```
[
      {
      "id" : "...",
      "category" : "...",
      "header" : "...",
      "body" : "..."
   },
      {
      "id" : "...",
      "category" : "...",
      "header" : "...",
      "body" : "..."
   }
]
```

**What i want:**

```
{
  "offers" : [ {
    "id" : "...",
    "category" : "...",
    "header" : "...",
    "body" : "..."
     },
     {
    "id" : "...",
    "category" : "...",
    "header" : "...",
    "body" : "..."
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just create that object yourself:

```
var obj = { offers : results };
```

(where `results` is your Mongoose result set).

Comment: Aah that was maybe the best and easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using the lodash module in npm, we can select the required felid in JSON respone

```
   import mongoose from 'mongoose'
   import pick from 'lodash/pick'



    UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () 
       let user = this
       let userObject = user.toObject()
       return pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email'])
       }
```